# How to test a function call that should fail?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

Im using Truffle to test my smart contracts written in Solidity and I would like to mark test as passed if function call/execution fails.

Example:

```
await instance.cancelOrder({from: accounts[1]});
```

Normaly this would pass if function executes properly. This one requires certain variable to be *true* which it isn't and **should** fail. How do I do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can call that certain variable right after this and check whether it is `true` or `false` according to your need. Let say the above call update the variable `orderCanceled` in the smart contract to `true`.

Right after this call you can also make an another call to get the value of `orderCanceled` and check whether it is as per desired or not (let say `true`). See the below example.

```
await instance.cancelOrder({from: accounts[1]});
let orderCanceled = await instance.methods.orderCanceled().call();
assert.equal(true, orderCanceled);
```

Hope it gives you some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [Truffle Assertions](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions) package? The method `truffleAssert.fails` asserts "that the passed async contract function fails with a certain ErrorType and reason." There's also `truffleAssert.reverts` for the specific case of a revert failure. Here's an example from the docs:

```
await truffleAssert.reverts(
  contractInstance.methodThatShouldRevert(),
  "only owner"
);
```